# IE 11 how to auto open Excel on download?

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer

I have an angular 2 app. It is using 3rd party to create an xls file and download it. This option works fine in Chrome however in IE the users want the option for it to automatically open instead of have to click Save then open.

Notice how the Save and Open option is grayed out.

[image]

Comment: [How to enable the 'Save and Open' option in Internet Explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/856108/how-to-enable-the-save-and-open-option-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Yea that didnt work. I tried that already.